# Flexbox Img with percantage behaves not as expected

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, navbar

I want to create a navbar with a linked image using flexbox.

But as soon as i try to use percentage for the image the whole image positions is on the left side of the page.
How do i fix this? is percentage with flexbox not usable? What am I doing wrong?

CodePen to my problem.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKQZWg

**Edit** *Grammar*

**HTML**

```
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Test</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/MBfRz8M.png" alt="Logo" id="test"></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;:
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

body{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-areas:    "header"
                            "main"
                            "footer";
}

header{
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: pink;
}

header nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
}

header nav a img{
    max-width: 30%;
}

header nav ul li{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: 30% of a , does a has a known width in CSS to be used for img 's width calculation ?  ex https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJqvWj

Comment: Well i have not given it a width but with your help everything seems to work now. thanks for your help!